# Extreme values using proc sql

Tags: sas

I have a dataset of customers of a grocery store with information including name, customer id, gender, date of birth, customer type, etc.

DOB is in the format of DDMMMYYYY such as 25JAN1990.

Customer types include online shopper, gold member, silver member, etc.

I need to print a table that identifies the youngest and oldest customers for each customer type using PROC SQL. I'm not sure where to even start with this. I have a rough idea of grouping by customer type and using max and min function on dates but I am not sure if that will work or if I can implement it.

```
PROC SQL;


quit;
```

Comment: Showing us some sample data and/or the code you've tried so far might be helpful for this one.

Comment: This is homework, I suggest reviewing your course notes. Searching for PROC SQL examples/tutorials will lead you to a lot of solutions as well. http://support.sas.com/kb/25/279.html

Comment: https://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/sqlproc/69822/HTML/default/viewer.htm#n14h1jmh2m9ul5n1svufdilalwjz.htm

Answer (score 0):

I think the important bit of this task is the SQL command *having*, which allows you to do comparisons withing the select statement. 
Since there is no clear beginning data, I've taken liberty to produce some.

```
data begin;
    input ID Test $ date mmddyy10.; 
    cards;
    001 A 09/01/2011 
    001 A 10/02/2011 
    001 A 09/12/2012 
    001 A 10/10/2013 
    001 B 10/01/2011 
    001 B 01/01/2012 
    002 A 10/12/2014 
    002 A 10/13/2014 
    002 A 02/02/2015 
    002 A 11/15/2015
    ;
run;

proc sql;
    select * from begin 
    group by ID, test /*These are the grouping variables*/
    having date=max(date) or date=min(date); /*Conditions that must be fulfilled*/
quit;
```

More about *having* and *group by*: http://www.dofactory.com/sql/having